# Strings to class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, class

I have a class in Ruby (on Rails) as follows:

```
class Good
  include MongoMapper::Document
  has_many :offers, :dependent => :destroy

  key :name,         String
  key :description,  String
  key :email,        String
  key :offers,       Array
  key :type,         String
end
```

I am parsing a JSON object from an external URL and retrieve only a partial set of the types in this class, ie, I can retrieve only name, description, and type. On my server, I already have a page and data that can be displayed. I would like to display the data from the external URL on the page as well. How can I do this without making too many changes to the code? One thing I thought of was to make the strings I retrieve a part of the class Good, but I have no idea of how I can do it.

In other words, the retrieved name, description and type will be cast into the type Good and then will use the existing page, created to display our goods to display both, our, and the retrieved goods. How can I do this? Is this the right way of going about it?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you want to achieve? Samples of code or desired output may make it easier to understand.

Comment: @MarkThomas: I have a UI to display our goods. It is bound to the Good class and is kinda configured for it. I need to use the same page to display this new information too. Since the fields match, I thought I can somehow make these retrieved strings a type of the class Good, and use the same UI page to display all info - our own, and the retrieved info. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you saying that you have Goods in MongoDB, and are retrieving Goods from a web service, and want to use the same model for both? What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear, but I'll take a shot. You could have a [`Struct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) like

```
ArbitraryGood = Struct.new(:name, :description, :type)
```

You could then map a collection of `Good` instances to this

```
@arbitrary_goods = Good.all.map { |g| ArbitraryGood.new(g.name, g.description, g.type) }
```

Then you can gather your JSON response and append new `ArbitraryGood` instances to it.

```
objects_from_json = ... # for you to implement
@arbitrary_goods += objects_from_json.map { |o| ArbitraryGood.new(o.name, o.description, o.type) }
```

Now `@arbitrary_goods` contains a single listing mixed with data from both `Good` instances and the parsed external JSON for use within your view.

Comment: This pretty much answers my question. I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thanks! :)

Comment: But would this mean that I would have to configure my html.erb file to match ArbitraryGood's definition?

Comment: I have no idea what your view looks like so I can't possibly answer that.